# Is there something wrong with my AC coil?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I set my thermostat to 21°C (69°F) while it's 26°C (78.8°F) outside.

The AC has been running non-stop for a few days. I managed to open a panel in the AC unit and take a picture of the AC coils. (See picture below.) I saw ice on the left and middle coils, but I didn't see any ice on the right coil (circled in red).

I have a theory that the left and middle coils are covered in ice because they're being overworked, given that the coil on the right might be broken. Am I correct? Does the AC coil need repair or replacement?

[image: My AC coils]

Comment: I"ve had the same problem , it was caused by high humidity,  A temporary fix is to simply turn the  unit off and let all the ice melt off.  Others are right, your fan speed, if adjustable, should be set as high as possible for A/C

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible causes for this. The most common causes are:

- A refrigerant leak - the system will cool poorly or not at all until this leak is repaired and the system is recharged.
- A plugged filter - low airflow causes this exact issue. Check the filter.
- A problem with the controls or fan - low airflow or fan motor issues can cause this.
- Plugged ducting - sensing a theme here? Low airflow is a common cause of this.

Good luck! If it still happens with a new filter and all the vents opened, you need an HVAC pro to take a look at this, because it's most likely to be a leak.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I intentionally omitted this detail earlier, but I had an HVAC professional examine my air conditioner. He assured me that the refrigerant was in good condition and not leaking. He proceeded to inspect the AC unit inside my house, focusing on the blower fan. According to him, my 1.5-ton AC unit is undersized for my 1500 sq ft townhouse. He suggested that I require a minimum of a 2-ton AC unit, which would cost me at least $3000 CDN. Although I don't believe he was attempting to upsell without reason, I do find myself questioning his expertise.

Comment: An undersized unit or an oversized unit will also freeze up. However, you aren't making huge demands of this unit, which leads me to believe you have an airflow problem. Please don't intentionally leave out details when you are asking a question here. It is impolite.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your coil.

Something wrong with the fan.

Does the fan has different speed setting (higher), check the manual for that.

If the fan does not provide enough airflow over the coil, the water will condesate and eventual freeze.

Temporary remedy : Try setting the temp to 24 to see if  the AC can do that, before spending money on larger AC.